# SQLite strftime function issue with timezone

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, group-by, sum

I have following table structure where are saved some dates:

I tried to group results by hours using strftime sqlite function, but i found the problem if datetime value is stored like:

```
2015-01-21 11:49:16CET
```

In this case is value not converted. But if i erased "CET" value to have something like this:

```
2015-01-21 10:44:09
```

I got the correct result.

**Query:**

```
SELECT strftime('%H', dc.date) as hr,
       COUNT(*) AS DIALS_CNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'APPT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS APPT_CNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'CONV_NO_APPT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CONVERS_CNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'CANNOT_REACH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CANNOT_REACH_CNT
FROM dialed_calls dc
GROUP BY strftime('%H', dc.date);
```

Should i remove timezone from date column or how can i solve it please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Do all values have the same timezone?

Comment: Yes, have same timezone. CET

Comment: Then you don't actually need it, do you?

Comment: Now not, but in nearest future yes. I asked on, how can i solve it with timezones.

Comment: The built-in date functions do not support custom timezones.

Comment: You can specify the timezone as `2015-01-21 10:44:09+01:00`. The only problem is that you have to change that to `+02:00` during summer time.